# How to run Scheduled task after specific CommandLineRunner?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I do some initializations in a CommandLineRunner's `run` function and I want my `Scheduled` task to begin schedule after the initialization, how can I achive this?
For example, I have the CommandLineRunner:

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Initializations
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the task scheduler:

```
public class SchedClass {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = ONE_SECOND)
    public void sched() {
    }
}
```

What can I do to make `sched()` runs after `run()` runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MySchedulingConfigurer implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar;
    private IntervalTask task;

    public MySchedulingConfigurer(IntervalTask task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        this.taskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
    }

    public void resume() {
        this.taskRegistrar.scheduleFixedRateTask(task);
    }

}

@Configuration
class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MySchedulingConfigurer schedulingConfigurer;

    @Bean
    public MySchedulingConfigurer mySchedulingConfigurer() {
        IntervalTask task = new IntervalTask(new MyTask(), 5000L);
        return new MySchedulingConfigurer(task);
    }

    public static class MyTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("===>  task executed...");
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void startScheduler(ApplicationReadyEvent event){
       schedulingConfigurer.resume();
    }
}


@Component
class CacheLoadingRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MySchedulingConfigurer schedulingConfigurer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        schedulingConfigurer.resume();
    }

}
```

Comment: What If  the scheduled function needs to wait for all the `CommandLineRunners`, not just one?

Comment: One way could be to create a `CommandLineRunner` class with lower priority and call `schedulingConfigurer.resume();` from there. Annotate lower prioritized runner class with `@Order(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: Another way could be to write a function that is listening to `ApplicationReadyEvent` event and call `schedulingConfigurer.resume()` within this mehod. When all `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationArguments` classes complete, ready event will be fired.

Comment: I updated my code to listen for `ApplicationReadyEvent` that to be triggered after all `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationArguments` executed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `@EnableScheduling`

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
...
}
```

2) It makes no sense to denote Spring Boot application with `@Component`

**UPDATED**

It could be achieved manually. Provide a TaskScheduler

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

Inject it into `MyCommandLineRunner` along with `SchedClass` and run

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Autowired
    private SchedClass schedBean;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // ...
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> schedBean.sched(), ONE_SECOND);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My `@EnableScheduling` and `@SpringBootApplication` annotations are added to the `Application` class, which has the main function.

Comment: `MyCommandLineRunner ` is annotated with `@Component` which makes it a bean and start.

Comment: @hello.wjx ok, I missed that. Thought your runner is a standalone application

Comment: @hello.wjx updated my answer, maybe it could be useful for you

Comment: Then it's scheduling with `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler `, not with spring-boot's schedule framework.  And What if the scheduled function needs to wait for all the `CommandLineRunner`s ?